# Obfuscate multiple integer values to a fixed length value and read it back

Tags: java, jpa, hash, obfuscation

I'm trying to turn multiple integers into a fixed length hash value.... so far so good, however, I need to be able read and decode the hash later on and get my integers back.

To give a little more context, I'm generating a cursor based pagination for an API call that queries multiple tables. So I need to be able to obfuscate multiple table ID's into a string like hash, send it to Front End. Also, I need to be able to receive any cursor hash, decode it into multiple table ID's and query the tables from that ID onward.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What's the purpose of obfuscation? Just to prevent users from banging on your API? Could you instead store the required data in the user's session, which is encrypted?

Comment: @JimMischel that wouldn't work cause the front end should be able to set the value explicitly. Or even a mobile app/swagger should allow for that

Answer (score 0):

If you consider this a security feature e.g. to prevent users from enumerating the rows in the table by incrementing identifier you probably should generate these user-facing hashes randomly and store them with each table row. In this approach rows will have a shorter numeric primary key (usually better for indexes due to smaller size) and an external user-facing identifier (pretty much not guessable if you use a UUID).

Alternatively you can try to:

1. Generate hashes separately for each user while storing them in the session. You can use random hashes as long as you have a 1-to-1 mapping between a hash and a row identifier, they will be valid only for the user that opened the session.
2. Use strong symmetric cryptography (e.g. AES) to encode and decode a a salted value `salt + id`. This will make it harder to guess what is used to create the hash.

Your current approach with reversible function sounds like [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) or I'm getting paranoid :)